# Vim in-line navigation

Tags: vim

How can I skip a word ('w') without leaving the current line?

The cursor should stop at the end of the line. I believe a similar solution could be applied to other step sizes as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose? Why can't you just stop pressing `w`?

Comment: Because it is so much fun (: Now seriously, I find it easier to navigate in a single line that way. I map it to Ctrl+Right/Left and can easily navigate to the end and back without counting words, using the same keys (say I want to go to the 2nd word from the end of the line).  I'm not convinced this is the best setting, however, I got curious about how this can be configured in vim.

Comment: Second word from the end of the line: $b

Comment: @Thomas: I know there are other ways. I think it is convenient to use a smaller subset of navigation keys. For my tasks <Left>/<Right>/<C-Left>/<C-Right> do most of the work.

Comment: @Albert - Yes, but what's wrong with w and b keys? They do the same thing as Ctrl+Right, Left with half an effort? Not to mention that using arrows in the first place is really getting the hang of vim in the wrong way. But, not my place to tell people how to do thing ... to each his own ...

Comment: Because it doesn't work in insert mode. But again, maybe I'll change my VS ways to vim style one day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange request, but `:call search('\<\|\(\k\@!\S\)\+', 'W', line('.'))` should do the trick. To emulate the `w` movement, we have to search for the beginning of a keyword `\<`, or the beginning of a non-keyword non-whitespace `\(\k\@!\S\)\+`. We turn off wrapping (`'W'`), and limit the scope of the search function to the current line.

This stops at the last word in the line. If you also want a stop at the end of the line, add `\|$` to the regexp.

Alternatively, you could assemble a search command, like `/\%42l\(\<\|\(\k\@!\S\)\+\)`, but it's harder to put in the current line number (42 in this example), and deal with the 'wrapscan' setting.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your logic, however, it doesn't do a thing when I type it.

Comment: Huh? The `:call` is an Ex command; type it in normal mode. If you want to create an insert-mode mapping, you first have to go to normal mode via `<C-O>`, and end the Ex command with <Enter>.

Comment: Apparently it works in a *.py (python) file but not when editing .vimrc . Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

It's already not that easy to understand what you mean but you also forgot to say that you wanted it to work in *insert* mode.

Do you want to be able to move word-by-word in *insert* mode? Well, you probably already know that but **you are not supposed to do that.** That's what *normal* mode is for.

FIY that kind of navigation is possible in GVim on ubuntu by default.

It's quite easy to simulate:

```
inoremap <C-Right> <C-o>w
inoremap <C-Left> <C-o>b
```

but it's not a good idea.

I don't get the "The cursor should stop at the end of the line" part though.

Comment: "The cursor should stop at the end of the line" is the main issue here. I am looking for a functionality similar to 'w' that stays on the current line without leaving it (stays at the end of the line).